# Data race when passing pointer to std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, clang, c++14

I am puzzled by a thread-sanitizer report which occurs for both GCC 8 and Clang 9 (I haven't tried others). There is a struct `Bar` with the following code:

```
struct Bar {

    Bar(bool create_foo) {
        ... 
        if (create_foo) {
            mFoo = new Foo();
            mFooThread = std::thread(&Foo::Run, mFoo); // This is a Data Race?!?!?!?
            mOther->setFoo(mFoo);
        }
        ... 
    }

    ~Bar() {
        if (mFooThread.joinable()) mFooThread.join();
    }

    Foo * mFoo;
    std::thread mFooThread;
    Other * mOther;
}
```

Running the thread sanitizer on Ubuntu 18.04 with both compilers says that the thread creation line (see comment above) is a data race. The only other place where that thread is used (`mFooThread`) is in the `Bar` destructor.

To give more details... the thread sanitizer reports 18 errors. 2 of them don't seem to have anything to do with the current project. The rest all point to this line. The confusing thing is that the errors don't seem to point to any other part of the codebase. They just seem to be circularly pointing to this line. Only one `Bar` object is created in the program, which makes me wonder why I see 16 errors.

The 2 errors that I believe are not related to the project are these:

```
Lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) (pid=3891)
Mutex M2925 acquired here while holding mutex M2921 in main thread:
pthread_mutex_lock
CPLAcquireMutex
Mutex M2921 acquired here while holding mutex M2925 in main thread:
pthread_mutex_lock
CPLCreateOrAcquireMutexEx

Lock-order-inversion (potential deadlock) (pid=3891)
Mutex M2922 acquired here while holding mutex M2921 in main thread:
pthread_mutex_lock
CPLAcquireMutex
Mutex M2921 acquired here while holding mutex M2922 in main thread:
pthread_mutex_lock
CPLCreateOrAcquireMutexEx
```

For reference, this is a Cmake project which I did not create, but which seems to have some threading issues as users have reported that the program randomly hangs. I turned on the thread sanitizer like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=${sanitize}")
set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=${sanitize}")
```

EDIT:

The following is the TSAN output for one of the data race warnings. They are all very similar:

```
Write of size 8 at 0x7b5000018500 by thread T29:
memset
g_slice_alloc0
Previous write of size 8 at 0x7b5000018500 by thread T15 (mutexes: write M3854):
posix_memalign
(libglib-2.0.so.0+0x690e6)
void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
std::__invoke_result<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>::type std::__invoke<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<0ul>(), _S_declval<1ul>())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>)
std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::operator()()
std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker>::_M_run()
(libstdc++.so.6+0xbd6de)

Location is heap block of size 496 at 0x7b5000018400 allocated by thread T15:
posix_memalign
(libglib-2.0.so.0+0x690e6)
void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
std::__invoke_result<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>::type std::__invoke<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<0ul>(), _S_declval<1ul>())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>)
std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::operator()()
std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker>::_M_run()
(libstdc++.so.6+0xbd6de)

Mutex M3854 (0x7b0c00536f70) created at:
pthread_mutex_init
(libglib-2.0.so.0+0x91e2c)
void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
std::__invoke_result<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>::type std::__invoke<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<0ul>(), _S_declval<1ul>())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>)
std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::operator()()
std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker>::_M_run()
(libstdc++.so.6+0xbd6de)

Thread T29 'gdbus' (tid=5438, running) created by thread T15 at:
pthread_create
(libglib-2.0.so.0+0x9240f)
void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(std::__invoke_memfun_deref, void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
std::__invoke_result<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>::type std::__invoke<void (Foo::*)(), Foo*>(void (Foo::*&&)(), Foo*&&)
decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<0ul>(), _S_declval<1ul>())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>)
std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple>::operator()()
std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker>::_M_run()
(libstdc++.so.6+0xbd6de)

Thread T15 (tid=5423, running) created by main thread at:
pthread_create
std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete>, void (*)())
Bar::Bar(bool)
main
```

Comment: Maybe off-topic, but calling `join` in the destructor is dangerous since `join` could throw an exception.  You need to surround the `join` call with a `try / catch`.

Comment: Does it still report a data race if you comment the line `mOther->setFoo(mFoo);`?

Comment: Tried, but has no effect on the data race results.

Comment: Need reproducible code. problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: That is entirely possible. I thought that perhaps there is some weird side effect of the thread constructor that I was not aware of.

Comment: Can you add the complete tsan output for the data race warning?